# angularjs - unit test, unable to call factory method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angularjs-factory

I'm having an hard time trying to call a factory method from karma unit test.

It says that the method that i'm trying to call (`load()`) does not exist.

Here's the code:

**unitTest.js**

```
describe('Data Factory', function() {
  var DataFactory, scope, spy;

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $rootScope, _ZoneData_) {
    var DataFromjson;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    DataFromjson = _ZoneData_;
    return spy = spyOn(DataFromjson, 'load');
  }));

  return it('Should Load the right data from the json file', function() {
    var test;
    test = DataFactory;
    console.log(test);
    return expect(DataFactory).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

and here's the factory code:

```
angular.module('services', ['ngResource']).factory('ZoneData', [
  '$http', '$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams) {
    var ZoneData;
    ZoneData = function(Data) {
      if (Data) {
        return this.setData(Data);
      }
    };
    ZoneData.prototype = {
      setData: function(Data) {
        return angular.extend(this, Data);
      },
      load: function(id) {
        var scope;
        scope = this;
        return $http.get('default-system.json').success(function(Data) {
          return scope.setData(Data.data);
        }).error(function(err) {
          return console.error(err);
        });
      },
      filtered: function() {
        var scope;
        scope = this;
        return $http.get('default-system.json').success(function(Data) {
          return angular.forEach(Data.data, function(item) {
            var urlZoneId;
            urlZoneId = parseInt($stateParams.zoneID);
            if (item.iID === urlZoneId) {
              return scope.setData(item);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };
    return ZoneData;
  }
])
```

any help with a bit of explanation will be really really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Isn't load() actually ZoneData.prototype.load() and NOT just ZoneData.load()?

Comment: as you can see, i have a console.log in my test, and this is the result: function (Data) {
      if (Data) {
        return this.setData(Data);
      } if it helps in any way
    }

Comment: I want to call Zonedata.prototype.load(), in my controller, i call this method like this: 
    $scope.zones = new ZoneData();
    $scope.zones.load();

Comment: Try that with $scope.zones.prototype.load();

Comment: Where exactly? sorry this is my first unit test ever. What i have to replace?

Comment: Does you controller and factory run as expected? Is the load() method working properly? NOT in the test case but actually working?

Comment: Yes, it is working properly in my controller and in my app

Comment: Hey Nick, It could be the fact you're injecting `_ZoneData_` but not actually assigning it to anything you're using -- i.e you assign it to `DataFromjson` but then use `DataFactory` -- let me know if this is the issue and i'll turn it into an answer edit: spelling

Comment: Hi, no, still the same issue: load() method does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with your factory implementation rather than the test.
A factory in Angular is supposed to return an object and what you are returning is an object 'constructor' function.

An easy solution would be to change the return value of your factory to be

`return new ZoneData();`

instead of returning

`return ZoneData;`

Please check this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/O8wnmgSQ8mc9t93jKDJ6?p=preview.
I have created a stripped down version of the factory just to demonstrate the concept.

Thanks.